# I am getting null as an output in Java

Tags: java

I have tried reading the other questions. It seems that this one is different.

So below in the `Results()` method I tried to display the voters name below the Nominees but for some reason it displays null or in below in another Nominee.

```
public class Vote{

    String a, b, c, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5;
    int va, vb, vc, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6;

    public void Main_Menu(){
        String n;
        Scanner Menu = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.println("1. Vote");
        System.out.println("2. Credits");
        System.out.println("3. Exit");
        n = Menu.next();
        if (n.equals("1")){
            Voting();
        }
        else if (n.equals("2")){
            System.out.print("Continue");
        }
        else if (n.equals("3")){
            exit();
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("Please input Numbers 1, 2, 3,");
        }
    }

    public void exit(){
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void Voting(){
        Scanner Nominees = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter 1st Nominee: ");
        a = Nominees.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter 2nd Nominee: ");
        b = Nominees.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter 3rd Nominee: ");
        c = Nominees.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Nominees are: " + (a) +", " + (b)+ ", " + (c));
        Confirm();
    }

    public void Confirm(){
        String s;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Confirm Nomimees ? A.Yes or B.No");
        s = in.next();
        if (s.equals("A")){
            Y();
        }
        else if (s.equals("B")){
             Voting();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Please Enter A or B ");
            Confirm();
        }
        in.close();
    }

    public void Y(){
        v1(); 
    }

    public void v1(){
        Scanner usrinp1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Voters Name: ");
        v1 = usrinp1.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Choose your Vote: " + "1." + (a) + " 2." + (b) + " 3." + (c));
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String c1;
        c1 = in1.next();
        if (c1.equals("1")){
            r1++;
            va++;
            v2();
        }
        else if (c1.equals("2")){
            r2++;
            vb++;
            v2();
        }
        else if (c1.equals("3")){
            r3++;
            vc++;
            v2();
        }
        else{            
            System.out.println("Please enter numbers 1, 2, & 3");
            v1();
        }
        in1.close();
    }

    public void v2(){
        Scanner usrinp2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Voters Name: ");
        v1 = usrinp2.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Choose your Vote: " + "1." + (a) + " 2." + (b) + " 3." + (c));
        Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String c2;
        c2 = in2.next();
        if (c2.equals("1")){
            r4++;
            va++;
            Results();
        }
        else if (c2.equals("2")){
            r5++;
            vb++;
            Results();
        }
        else if (c2.equals("3")){
            r6++;
            vc++;
            Results();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Please enter numbers 1, 2, & 3");
            v2();
        }
        in2.close();    
    }

    public void Results(){
        System.out.println((a) + "=" + (va));
        if (r1==1){
            System.out.print(v1);
        }

        if (r4 == 1){
            System.out.print(v2);
        }

        System.out.println("\n"+(b) + "=" + (vb));
        if (r2 == 1){
            System.out.print(v1);
        }
        if (r5 == 1){
            System.out.println(v2);
        }

        System.out.println("\n"+(c) + "=" + (vc));
        if (r3 == 1){
            System.out.println(v1);
        }
        if (r6 == 1){
            System.out.println(v2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to re-think your variable names, it's very confusing to read

Comment: Please start variable names and method names with a lower case letter, as by convention in Java.

Comment: Poor style of writing code,please improve.

Comment: @martijnn2008 all my variables are in lower case letters.

Comment: `Scanner Menu = new Scanner(System.in);`, don't think so ;)

Comment: @martijnn2008 i changed it to lower case letters, yet it doesn't resolve the problem. I'm sorry for my poor writing guys, I am new to Java, coding in General

Comment: The method names are not Correct. You better read some java beginner tutorial.

Comment: Also read: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](//stackoverflow.com/q/13102045) // [java.util.NoSuchElementException - Scanner reading user input](//stackoverflow.com/q/13042008)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your code was very hard. A method and a variable with the same name is bound to cause confusion. Anyway: You are never assigning any value to the field `v2`, so it is always printed as `null` — the default value that fields have when created.

It maybe a copy-paste error where you forgot to change `v1` to `v2` after pasting. You can best tell yourself.

Next time please see if you can do a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I bet you will find the error before getting your question ready for posting. :-)

Comment: Thank you mate, thanks for being patient.